# Netcat xxx.xxx.x.xx: inverse host lookup failed: h_errno 11004: NO_DATA

Tags: netcat, data-stream

I am using netcat on Windows 10 to fetch a data stream from a data acquisition module. The command I'm using is:

`nc -u -l -vv -p 5168 > log.txt`

But then, looking at the verbose, I got:

```
listening on [any] 5168 ...
xxx.xxx.x.xx: inverse host lookup failed: h_errno 11004: NO_DATA
connect to [xxx.xxx.x.xxx] from (UNKNOWN) [xxx.xxx.x.xx] 5168: NO_DATA
```

And on the log.txt file, I'm getting y with diaeresis which I was not expecting:

[log.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xzf1.png)

How do I solve this issue? I know that this problem doesn't come from the data acquisition module because I've seen results from others who uses the same module to fetch data with netcat in hex format. I've also tried it with ncat but still got the same results. Please help. And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

are you using vpn like openvpn ?
try:

```
nc -lvp PORT -s ipOfYourVpnInterface
```

Cordially